# 'list' object is not callable when building one-hot vector

Tags: python, list, one-hot-encoding

I was trying to construct a one-hot encoding system by using Python 3.7 + Jupyter notebook, and I ran into an error like this:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-0fc633482cfd> in <module>
      1 for i, sample in enumerate(samples):
----> 2     for j, word in list(enumerate(sample.split()))[:max_length]:
      3         index = all_token_index.get(word)
      4         result[i,j,index] = 1

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Here are the original code:

```py
import numpy as np

samples = ['This is a dog','This is a cat']

all_token_index = {} 

for sample in samples:
    for word in sample.split():  
        if word not in all_token_index:  
            all_token_index[word] = len(all_token_index) + 1

max_length = 10
result = np.zeros(shape=(len(samples), max_length, max(all_token_index.values()) + 1 )) 

for i, sample in enumerate(samples):
    # Get keys and values in sample
    for j, word in list(enumerate(sample.split()))[:max_length]: 
        index = all_token_index.get(word)
        result[i,j,index] = 1
```

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm betting that somewhere earlier in your code you named a variable `list` and overwrote the builtin `list` function.  Go back and give that variable a better name!  :)

Comment: It works for me though

Comment: Works fine here. The posted code seems correct.

Comment: @Samwise no, there is no variable named `list`

Comment: See first comment, when I declare a list with list=[], the error is reproduced. Indeed, it is very likely that somewhere else in your code you have define a list named list.

Comment: @Samwise You are right, it occurred to me that there was a variable named `list` in one deleted notebook cell. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was given by @Samwise and @Ronald in the comments. Like they said, I used a `list` variable in one deleted notebook cell. After restarting the notebook, the problem was fixed.